# Error en mi código VB. NET sistema Biblioteca

Tags: vb.net

> Al seleccionar todos los Ítem y quitarlos "todos" no aumenta el stock en el libro que corresponde, solo lo aumenta al primer ID. Pero si
>   selecciono solo uno de ellos si funciona a la perfección. Todos los
>   registros están en DatagridView donde al querer quitar "eliminar" los
>   registros se añade una columna con un checkbox solo los que están con
>   un checked seran eliminados, al seleccionar todos los checkeds y eliminar todos ocurre un error
>   "la función aumentar cantidad solo aumenta al primer Item y no a los
>   que corresponde".

```
 Dim result As DialogResult
            result = MessageBox.Show("Realmente decea quitar los libros seleccionados?", "Eliminando registros", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel)

            If result = DialogResult.OK Then
                Try
                    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgvdetalleprestamo.Rows
                        Dim marcado As Boolean = Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells("Eliminar").Value)
                        If marcado Then
                            Dim onekey As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells("coddetallepres").Value)
                            Dim vdb As New vdetalle_prestamo
                            Dim func As New fdetalle_prestamo
                            vdb.gcoddetallepres = onekey
                            vdb.gcodlib = dgvdetalleprestamo.SelectedCells.Item(3).Value
                            vdb.gcodpre = dgvdetalleprestamo.SelectedCells.Item(2).Value
                            vdb.gcantidad = dgvdetalleprestamo.SelectedCells.Item(5).Value


                        If func.eliminar(vdb) Then
                            If func.aumentar_cantidad(vdb) Then

                            End If
                            cboeliminar.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked
                        Else
                            MessageBox.Show("Libro no fue retirado", "Quitando libros", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
                        End If
                    End If

                Next
                Call mostrar()
```

> La función AUMENTAR CANTIDAD DEBIERA IR AHÍ?

```
    Public Function aumentar_cantidad(ByVal dts As vdetalle_prestamo)
            Try
                conectado()
                cmd = New SqlCommand("aumentar_cantidad")
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                cmd.Connection = cnn
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@codlib", dts.gcodlib)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cantidad", dts.gcantidad)

                If cmd.ExecuteNonQuery Then
                    Return True
                Else
                    Return False
                End If
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.Message)
                Return False
            Finally
                desconectado()
            End Try
        End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema es no haber hecho un debug de tu codigo.

Hay un error muy visible:

```
'recorres toda la grilla
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgvdetalleprestamo.Rows
    Dim marcado As Boolean = Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells("Eliminar").Value)
    If marcado Then
        'trabajas con la fila que estas recorriendo, bien
        Dim onekey As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells("coddetallepres").Value)
        Dim vdb As New vdetalle_prestamo
        Dim func As New fdetalle_prestamo
        vdb.gcoddetallepres = onekey
        'y aca usas la fila seleccionada, no la que estas recorriendo, NO!
        vdb.gcodlib = dgvdetalleprestamo.SelectedCells.Item(3).Value
        vdb.gcodpre = dgvdetalleprestamo.SelectedCells.Item(2).Value
        vdb.gcantidad = dgvdetalleprestamo.SelectedCells.Item(5).Value
```

Fijate que usas dos conceptos distintos dentro del for. Recorres las filas una a una, pero para eleminar usas solo la fila seleccionada, que por suerte en tu grilla es una sola (porque podrias seleccionar mas de una).

Para un solo elemento anda, porque la fila seleccionada es donde acabas de hacer click sobre el checkbox.

Comment: Lo resolví, eran tan claro. Gracias hermano tenias toda la razón.